# Can Vesuva copy a land that comes the same time into play as itself?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When I tutor [Vesuva](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVesuva%5d) and another land with my [Primeval Titan](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPrimeval%20Titan%5d), can I let Vesuva be a copy of that other land?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.** From the [comprehensive rules](https://magic.wizards.com/en/game-info/gameplay/rules-and-formats/rules):

> 614.12a If a replacement effect that modifies how a permanent enters the battlefield requires a choice, that choice is made before the permanent enters the battlefield.

Vesuva and the other land enter the battlefield at the same time. However the choice of which land to copy must be made before Vesuva enters the battlefield, which means the other land isn't on the battlefield yet either, so it can't be chosen.

Comment: Is this being changed with the Blood Moon / Shockland change coming up?

Comment: @xornob, The rule that's been changed doesn't apply here since nothing causes Vesuva to lose its ability. If something was (e.g. Blood Moon or Magus of the Moon), then Vesuva wouldn't be able to copy anything at all under the new rules.

Comment: Man, I want to make Magus of the Moon + Dark Depths deck :D